# Omnet++ and MiXiM

Tags: c++, networking, simulator, omnet++, mixim

I am trying to run simulations for 802.15.4a devices.
For this reason I am using MiXiM which provides very useful modules.

More specifically I want to have a first (very easy) configuration where two Host802154A communicate with each other.

I then created a network.ned as follows

```
package eval;
import inet.physicallayer.ieee802154.bitlevel.Ieee802154UWBIRRadioMedium;
import org.mixim.modules.node.Host802154A;


//
// TODO documentation
//
network env
{
    @display("bgb=639,446");
    submodules:
        dev1: Host802154A {
            @display("p=128,166");
        }
        dev2: Host802154A {
            @display("p=402,166");
        }
        ieee802154Medium: Ieee802154UWBIRRadioMedium {
            @display("p=513,37");
        }
}
```

I checked many guides to run experiments but I am not sure I understood how to 'start'.

I need an omnetpp.ini file but what should it contain?

Do I have to define two .cc files for dev1 and dev2?

I just want to have the two devices exchanging messages, nothing more than that.

Comment: Did you read the OMNeT++ documentation and done some of the tutorials (most importantly, the TicToc tutorial)?

Comment: Yes of course, I think that the main problem was that MiXiM is not supported by omnet++ 5.0.
I installed version 4 and I am now able to run examples from MiXiM library which gave me a better overview of the simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you are going to need an omnetpp.ini file.
Check the OMNeT++ manual and the most important tutorial - [the TicToc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial)

A (bit outdated) quick-start guide is available here: https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.OmnetppInNutshell

As for additional .cc files, if you rely on standard host definitions from MiXiM, you wont need any additional .cc files.
The basic MiXiM examples provide more insight on how MiXiM hosts and classes are instantiated and used, while the omnetpp.ini will provide the correct parametrization.